# Hibernate defining table in @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new in Hibernate. What is the difference between

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
```

and

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false, etc)
private Integer id;
```

What is the reason of defining this if we already did it creating database? Does Hibernate warn us when we break these constraints (not in this example since it's auto generated value)? Does it create table when there isn't one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason is if the column is named differently, for example in a `USER` table, if the id column is called `USER_ID`, you might want to map that to a `User` object, on the field `id`.

The unique and nullable attributes are not used, as PK are unique and non-null. Read the javadoc of [`@Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) to understand what else you can define there.

As you mentioned, if you create your DB from scripts (it's actually a bad practice to create your production DB from the JPA annotations), the only relevant attribute is the name... the other ones are not used for `@Id` columns or are used to autogenerate the DDL.

A slight word of caution, sometimes the attribute `nullable` influences on how updates are ordered. As a good practice, I always set it to `false` on mandatory associations (as otherwise Hibernate might decide *clear* the association and set the column to null... and then do another update with the new ID.).